# When does Hom commute with $\otimes$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra and $M,N$ are finitely generated $A$-module. Is it true that $Hom(A,M\otimes_A N)\cong Hom(A,M)\otimes_A Hom(A,N)$, as $A$-modules? This is definitely true if $Hom(A, M) \cong M$ for any finitely generated $A$-module $M$. Is the latter true as well? Or is there some additional conditions making these true? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what is the map giving this isomorphism? Or do you have any references? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\hom_A(A, M) \simeq M$ the maps are $\phi \mapsto \phi(1)$ and in the other direction $m \mapsto \lambda_m$ where $\lambda_m\colon A \to M$ is defined by $\lambda_m(a) = am$.  Note I'm making no assumptions on $A$ or $M$, they needn't be commutative, finite dimensional, finitely generated, or anything like that.  We just need that $A$ has a $1$ and the module structure of $M$ respects $1 \in A$.

*Edit:* I also want to point out that in general Hom and tensor don't commute.  This is very specificaly due to the fact that you are taking Hom out of the ring $A$.  For example, if $A = k$ is a field and the modules are finitely generated then $\hom_k(P, M \otimes_k N) \simeq P^\ast \otimes_k M \otimes_k N$ is not the same as $\hom_k(P, M) \otimes_k \hom_k(P, N) \simeq P^\ast \otimes_k M \otimes_k P^\ast \otimes_k N$.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great answer.